# Problems with images on screens with less than 360px

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to display a grid with images but on extra small screens (<360px), the width is stretching.I'm using tailwindcss and can't fix this.

[Image on 368px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRPFM.png)

[Image on 330px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ4yc.png)

```
<div class="break-words bg-white sm:border-1 sm:rounded-md sm:shadow-lg p-4 sm:p-6 xl:p-8">

    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-6">
        @foreach ($medias as $media)
            <div class="col-span-12 sm:col-span-6 md:col-span-3 lg:col-span-2 flex flex-col">
                @if ($media->getTypeFromMime() == 'image')
                    <img class="h-auto max-h-full w-full max-w-full rounded-lg" src="{{ $media->getFullUrl('thumbnail') }}"
                        alt="{{ $media->name }}" wire:click="mediaDetails('{{ $media->uuid }}')">
                @endif

            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Settings the width to 100% and autos doesn't fix

Comment: which screens are less than 360px with exception of first-generation iPhones? Even smartwatches exceed 360px nowadays. There is a reason why frameworks such as Tailwind and Bootstrap do not specifically support smaller screens.

Comment: @tacoshy when using the devices function in google chrome devtools, it shows a galaxy fold. I want to have the website 100% responsive for all devices but if tailwind doesn't support it I have nothing to do. Thanks for the answer.